# Writing Words with Special Characters for Notepad Use

Tags: text, software-recommendation

Is there any online fiddle, where I can create the following like words? And what is the term for this to search online?

```
       ____   __            ______ _      __     __ __    
      / __ \ / /_   ____   / ____/(_)____/ /____/ // /___ 
     / /_/ // __ \ / __ \ / /_   / // __  // __  // // _ \ 
    / ____// / / // /_/ // __/  / // /_/ // /_/ // // ___/
   /_/    /_/ /_// .___//_/    /_/ \__,_/ \__,_//_/ \___  
                /_/
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally, creating art/typography with characters online is called [ASCII art](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art). I did a brief search, and found this [ASCII generator](http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f=Graffiti&t=Type%20Something%20). Hopefully that'll help you make what you need.

Comment: This ASCII Generator is superior to most.